# How to change the backgroundColor of ListView Item when the item(Quantity) is less than 3

Tags: java, android, xml

In my `MainActivity.java` i want to programmatically set the backgound color of `ListView` item when the quantity is less than 3 and also please give me idea on how to do it.Thanks in advance.

this is my custom listview

single_product.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10000"
    android:textSize="24dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="51dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gal."
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="White"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wpu-01"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Weber"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Urethane"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Category" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Category"
    android:text="P"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:id="@+id/P"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10000.00"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/P"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="11"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here Mainactivity code

```
public void updateJSONdata() {

    orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(PRODUCTLIST_URL);


    try {


        order = json.getJSONArray(GET_PRODUCT);

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = order.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString(GET_ID);

            String brand = c.getString(GET_BRAND);

            String category = c.getString(GET_CATEGORY);

            String description = c.getString(GET_DESCRIPTION);

            String code = c.getString(GET_CODE);

            String quantity = c.getString(GET_QUANTITY);

            String unit = c.getString(GET_UNIT);

            String unitprice = c.getString(GET_UNITPRICE);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(GET_ID,id);

            map.put(GET_BRAND, brand);

            map.put(GET_CATEGORY, category);

            map.put(GET_DESCRIPTION, description);

            map.put(GET_CODE, code);

            map.put(GET_QUANTITY, quantity);

            map.put(GET_UNIT, unit);

            map.put(GET_UNITPRICE, unitprice);


            orderlist.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

private void updateList() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    smpadater = new SimpleAdapter(this, orderlist,

            R.layout.single_product, new String[] { GET_ID, GET_BRAND, GET_CATEGORY,

            GET_DESCRIPTION, GET_CODE, GET_QUANTITY, GET_UNIT, GET_UNITPRICE}, new int[]{R.id.ID, R.id.Brand, R.id.Category,

            R.id.Description, R.id.Code, R.id.Quantity, R.id.Unit, R.id.Price });

    lv.setAdapter(smpadater);

    smpadater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

```
final  public class LoadProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Order...");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        updateJSONdata();

        return null;

    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pDialog.dismiss();


        updateList();

    }

}
```

Comment: In your adapter class, you can check the condition whether the quantity is less than or more than 3. If the condition is true, then you can change the color of the list view item.

Comment: Can you provide sample on how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Post your adapter code here

Comment: I posted  my code above please check

Comment: why did you call notifyDataSetChanged() after setting the listview adapter. That is not required.

Comment: /w8 i will post the whole code

Comment: You have to use a custom Adapter for this

Comment: ahhh ok thanks for the help

Comment: Sir can you teach me on how create custom adapter for my custom listview i want something like this smpadater = new SimpleAdapter(this, orderlist, R.layout.single_product, new String[] { GET_ID, GET_BRAND, GET_CATEGORY, GET_DESCRIPTION, GET_CODE, GET_QUANTITY, GET_UNIT, GET_UNITPRICE}, new int[]{R.id.ID, R.id.Brand, R.id.Category, R.id.Description, R.id.Code, R.id.Quantity, R.id.Unit, R.id.Price }); lv.setAdapter(smpadater);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below class is CustomeAdapter,which will display your listview items.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<MyObjectClass> list;

public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<MyObjectClass> list) {
    this.list = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public MyObjectClass getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    MyObjectClass object = list.get(position);
    viewHolder.updateData(object);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvQuantity;
    private TextView tvID;
    private View convertView;
    private TextView tvCode, tvPrice, tvBrand, tvCategory, tvDescription;


    public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
        this.convertView = convertView;
        tvQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
        tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID);
        tvBrand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Brand);
        tvCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
        tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Description);
        tvCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Code);
        tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Price);
    }

    public void updateData(MyObjectClass object) {
        int quantity = object.getQuantity();
        if (quantity < 3) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            //Here your color value should same as default color of listView
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity) + "Gal");
        tvID.setText(object.getDescription());
        tvBrand.setText(object.getBrand());
        tvCategory.setText(object.getCategory());
        tvDescription.setText(object.getDescription());
        tvCode.setText(object.getCode());
        tvPrice.setText(object.getPrice());
    }
  }
}
```

From your activity class you can set the adapter to listView.

Something like this:

you can add any number of items which has all those details. FYI, I just added three items which has same details.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<MyObjectClass> list = new ArrayList<MyObjectClass>();
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        list.add(new MyObjectClass(QUNTITY,GET_ID,GET_BRAND,GET_CATEGORY,GET_DESCRIPTION,GET_CODE,GET_PRICE));
    }
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
```

Your object class should have those fields.

below is object class for your requirement.

```
public class MyObjectClass {
private int quantity;

private String id;
private String brand;
private String category;
private String description;
private String code;
private String price;

public MyObjectClass(int quantity, String id, String brand, String category, String description, String code, String price) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.id = id;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.category = category;
    this.description = description;
    this.code = code;
    this.price = price;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Comment: But how i can do it if i don't use BaseAdapter , I just simply use Simpleadapter

Comment: Why don't you use BaseAdapter, for this requirement you have to use BaseAdapter.

Comment: Hahaha I'm newbee in android app dev. and i do not  know to transform my code into baseadapter

Comment: Sir can you teach me on how create custom adapter for my custom listview i want something like this  smpadater = new SimpleAdapter(this, orderlist,

            R.layout.single_product, new String[] { GET_ID, GET_BRAND, GET_CATEGORY,

            GET_DESCRIPTION, GET_CODE, GET_QUANTITY, GET_UNIT, GET_UNITPRICE}, new int[]{R.id.ID, R.id.Brand, R.id.Category,

            R.id.Description, R.id.Code, R.id.Quantity, R.id.Unit, R.id.Price });

    lv.setAdapter(smpadater);

Comment: for your requirement I have posted my code, once use this. And let me if you have any queries.

Comment: i m glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the color on the getView method from your apdater:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    }

    if (your condition) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color1);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color2);
    }



    return view;
}
```

Comment: but Marta I do not use baseadapter

Comment: Ok sorry I answered you before you put the code of yor adapter :\ but anyway you must use a custom adapter if you want to modify your view depending of quantities.
If you are newbie in android you can start with ArrayAdapter. Follow this nice tutorial and focus on the part of "Using a Custom ArrayAdapter" https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView